# Manage the same file across multiple apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, devops

I have four or five small web apps that I build and maintain for a small group at work. For the most part, they have the same layout and file structure. A lot of the files are the exact same across the apps. Here's an example `index.js` file that's the same in every apps' `src/` directory.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  console.log(`Environment: ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
}

const root = document.querySelector('#root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

Copying and pasting works fine until I need to update something. A few months ago I started changing my React class components over to functional components with hooks. The only problem is I have to make that same change for every version of that file in every site.

I tried using [bit](https://bit.dev) and I thought about creating a local NPM package, but those aren't ideal options. I'd have to import each file and that doesn't really work the way I need. (I guess I could import the very first `index.js` file, but it doesn't seem like an ideal solution.)

I want to be able to edit a file in app A and next time I go back to work on app B be able to see the changes made to the file in A and pull them into B. That way I can make each of the shared files/components dynamic enough to work for all my apps. If the changes made on the file in app A don't work for app B, I can rework the file in app B and pull the changed next time I work on app A.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: A local NPM package would be the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [`git submodules`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) could be a valid option for you, especially for push/pull changes part.